# How do i deploy my wicket project?

Tags: deployment, wicket

i am new to web development and i created a wicket app on my local computer. i have a server running apache 2.0, maven and open jdk. Its an ubuntu server with only command line.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say apache 2.0?

Comment: i have apache 2 already install in the ubuntu server.

Comment: Sure, but which apache project do you mean? The apache http server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run the wicket app by itself; like any java servlet it has to be run on a servlet container.

There are many containers to choose from, the ones I most commonly come across are

- [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)
- [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/)
- [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)

You need to install one of containers like that to convert the HTTP requests into java. Once you have one of them installed and running, you can deploy your wicket web-app in it.